# Python: I can't find a string inside an Excel file exported to .txt: only one char

Tags: python, string, file, search, text

I exported an Excel sheet in TXT format; upon reading it in Python, I am not able to find strings insde it.

I tried several methods, none works: each one works only if I look for one character long string!
Why?!?

```
fname="elenco.txt"

counter=0
for line in open(fname):
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter>5:
        break
    if "AB" in line:
        print "funziona"
    print line
    
with open(fname, 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if 'T' in line:
            print "OK"
    
with open(fname) as f:
    content=f.readlines()
counter=0
for rec in content:
    test=rec[:len(rec)-5]
    print test, ">>>",test.find('TORINO')
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter>5:
        break
    #if rec.find("ABBIA")>0:
    #   print "Trovato: " + rec
print "Fine."
```

Comment: `"AB" in line` is the correct way to look for the substring `"AB"` in `line`. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Maybe there is only "Ab" or "ab" in the file and its a case problem.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong... but it does not work for me. It works with "A", but I don't get "funziona" printed if I search for "AB" or for any other string longer than  1 char.

Comment: This is weird: I figured out that the error was not in source code, but in text file!
Although it has .txt suffix and it looks like a standard text file in PSPad, it's not: running the script from DOS I discovered that there are "spaces" between each letter in the file... so I examined it with an hex editor, and I found that it's an unicode file!!
I don't know why it happened, I obtained the file by saving an Excel .xls file in .txt format.

Comment: All the more reason to show all the parts of the problem, like the input file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird: I figured out that the error was not in source code, but in text file!
Although it has .txt suffix and it looks like a standard text file in PSPad, it's not: running the script from DOS I discovered that there are "spaces" between each letter in the file... so I examined it with an hex editor, and I found that it's an unicode file!!
I don't know why it happened, I obtained the file by saving an Excel .xls file in .txt format.

Answer (score 2):

this works just fine for me:

```
fileList = open("filename", "r").readlines()

for line in fileList:
 if "string" in line:
  print line
```

Comment: It does not for me, if "string" is longer than 1 character. I'm using PortablePythonWin32 in Windows XP, and I wrote the script using PSPad editor which calls python executable passing the source as parameter to it, if this can help.

Answer (score 1):

Guess its a case problem. Try `if "AB" in line.upper()` instead of `if "AB" in line`.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I just needed to know the python equivalent for "UCASE$()".